# root cron job - limit log files?

Tags: scripts, cron, root

I'm running a cron job that is just "wget https://url" and it works find but is filling up my /root/ folder with output.  I'd like to cap the output to only save the last day or so if possible but am unsure how to do that and if I should from the cron scheduler or run a cleanup script or what exactly is best practice and how to implement that.

Comment: wget is merely a downloading tool. Managing what gets downloaded is outside what it is designed to do. So a cleanup script seems like a good option.

Comment: Thanks (apparently I can't upvote here yet)